# Random position for picturebox on a panel

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to generate a random position for my PictureBox which is in a Panel. I load my page with C#. This is my code for the PictureBox. How can I have a random position for it?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    PictureBox pictureboxtroll = new PictureBox();
    pictureboxtroll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 70);
    pictureboxtroll.BackColor = Color.Green;
    this.Controls.Add(pictureboxtroll);
}
```

Comment: You only have to learn, oh, about 5% of the .NET framework.  After which you'll know how to find the remaining 95% of it.  Asking somebody else to do the finding for you completely screws that up.  What can we do to not help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position of an element through its `Location` property:

```
// generate random position
Random random = new Random();
var viewRange = this.Size - pictureboxtroll.Size;
var left = random.Next(0, viewRange.Width);
var top = random.Next(0, viewRange.Height);

// set the random position
pictureboxtroll.Location = new Point(left, top);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the position of the pictureBox (X and Y coordinates) you have to acces it through the Location property like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
picturebox.Location.X = new Point(rand.Next(0,this.Widht));
pictureBox.Location.Y = new Point(rand.Next(0,this.Height));
```

And if you want that to execute when the Form1 object first loads then you need to place that little code snippet in the `Form_Load` event

Comment: If you want the PictureBox to be completely within your Panel, then subtract the PBs width/height from the Panel's width/height in your rand.Next() calls.